# ANTLR how to discriminate two similar comments

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In Antlr, if i have a rule for example:

```
> someRule : COMM TYPE arg EQUAL COMMENT_TEXT;
```

where:

- 'COMM' : is '|'
- 'TYPE'           : is ('C'|'I'|'U')
- 'arg'            : can be 'number,number'(1,0) or only a number (1)
- EQUALS           : '='
- COMMENT_TEXT     : String

it would accept :

```
-   | C10,1 = comment
-   | U10 = comment
```

In my grammar this rule is a DEFINITION.

When even one of these "token" is missing, I would like a generic comment:

```
|C1 comment   -> Generic Comment (EQUAL is missing)
|1 = comment  -> Generic comment ('type' is missing)
|C = Comment  -> Generic comment ('arg' is missing)
|comment      ....
```

Grammar:

```
currLine : commentType | .....; 

commentType: COMM (defComm | genComm); 

defComm: TYPE arg EQUAL COMMENT_TEXT #defcom;
```

how can i say that everything else is genComm?

genComm: ....

EDIT:

One possible solution can be:

```
genComment:
     : TYPE arg? EQUAL? COMMENT_TEXT?
     | arg EQUAL? COMMENT_TEXT?
     | EQUAL COMMENT_TEXT?
     | COMMENT_TEXT 
     ;
```

My Parser grammar:

```
parser grammar ParserComments;

options {
      tokenVocab = LexerComments;
  }

prog : (line? EOL)+;   
line : comment; 

comment: SINGLE_COMMENT (defComm | genericComment); 

defComm: TYPE arg EQUAL COMMENT_TEXT;

arg : (argument1) (VIRGOLA argument2)?;  
  
argument1    : numbers ;  
argument2    : numbers ;  
numbers      : NUMBER+ ;  
 
genericComment
 : TYPE arg? EQUAL? COMMENT_TEXT?
 | arg EQUAL? COMMENT_TEXT?
 | EQUAL COMMENT_TEXT?
 | COMMENT_TEXT 
 ; 

// ------ general  ------ 
ignored : . ;
```

My Lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar LexerComments;

SINGLE_COMMENT : '|' -> pushMode(COMMENT); 
NUMBER : [0-9];  
VIRGOLA : ',';
WS  : [ \t] -> skip ;   
EOL : [\r\n]+;  
 
// ------------ Everything INSIDE a COMMENT ------------ 
mode COMMENT;
    COMMENT_NUMBER  : NUMBER -> type(NUMBER);
    COMMENT_VIRGOLA : VIRGOLA -> type(VIRGOLA);
    
    TYPE : 'I'| 'U'| 'Q';
     
    EQUAL : '=';
    
    COMMENT_TEXT: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
     
    WS_1        : [ \t] -> skip ;   
    COMMENT_EOL : EOL -> type(EOL);
```

but parsing:

- | Q1,0 = text

I get a full context and ambiguity error in BaseErrorListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes seem to give you the results you want:

1 - you need to `popMode` out of `COMMENT` mode when you encounter an EOL:

```
COMMENT_EOL: EOL   -> type(EOL),popMode;
```

2 - you can use the following for your `genericComment` rule:

```
genericComment: .*?;
```

Basically says, match anything (but don't be greedy), so it won't match the `EOL` token.  As a result it will take any token up to the next `EOL` token.

[image]

BTW... your `ignored` rule is purely extraneous.  Parser rules are evaluated through a recursive descent calling structure.  If a rule is not a start rule, it can only be accessed by being referenced by another rule.

(It's not uncommon to have a final lexer rule that matches `.` (i.e. anything) to catch anything that prior Lexer rules did not match.  But that works because Lexer rules are not evaluated by a recursive descent algorithm)

Re: Lexer rules

The first step in ANTLR parsing your input, is to convert your input stream of characters into a stream of tokens. This process uses you Lexer rules (the rules that begin with a capital letter). At this time, the parser rules are irrelevant, the parser rules act on the stream of tokens that the Lexer produces.

When the Lexer (aka tokenizer), tokenizes your input characters, it will evaluate you input against all of your Lexer rules. When more than 1 rule can match your input, then there are two "tie-breaker" strategies:

The Lexer rule that matches the longest stream of input characters with take top priority.
If there is more than one rule that matches the same (longest) sequence of characters, then the rule that appears first "wins"

Comment: Thanks Mike, but with input:   `| Q1,0 = text` 
how can i resolve the ambiguity? the parser match defComm and genericComment apparently.

Comment: While there is *technically* an ambiguity, ANTLR resolves the ambiguity by selecting the first rule alternative, so the `genericComm` rule will only match input that is not matched by the `defComm` rule.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In my java program im parsing many lines of code and to avoid ambiguous lines I'm checking `lexerErrorListener.hasError()`  and  `parserErrorListener.hasError()` but in this way, I skip lines like ` | Q1,0 = text` . So in general is it better if I don't check these errors? or should I redirect them better?

Comment: I just described my doubt in this specific post
 [https://stackoverflow.com/q/71056312/18108156]

Comment: Hi Mike, how can i change my grammar to match an input like ` | Q1,0 = this is a comment` or after EQUAL match any character? input like  ` | Q1,0 = this is a comment` match genericComm instead of defComm... Thanks

Comment: your `COMMENT_TEXT` rule does not allow for whitespace, so even though you're ignoring `WS`, you will have multiple `COMMENT_TEXT` tokens in your token stream.  You could change your `defComm` rule to end with `COMMENT_TEXT+` (or more likely `COMMENT_TEXT*` in case there is no following text.)

Comment: Thanks Mike, this work with strings... i tried to modify COMMENT_TEXT to match any char with `COMMENT_TEXT: ~[ \r\n]*` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Yeah, that's going to make `COMMENT_TEXT` very aggressive in matching input.  The Lexer will use the rule that matches the longest sequence of characters, so that rule is going to "gobble up" input that you want to be other tokens.  If you want `defComm` to accept pretty much anything after the equal sign until EOL then replace the `COMMENT_TEXT` token in the `defComm` rule to use the `.*?` that we used in `genericComment`.

Comment: I've amended the answer to speak a bit about how Lexer Rules are evaluated, this may help in understanding what is going on.  Also... it's always a good idea to dump out the token stream so that you have a good grasp of how your lexer rules are tokenizing your input.l

Comment: As a first test I tried to use `COMMENT_TEXT: .*?` but the parser "never ends".  Maybe olso this lexer rule  in `mode COMMENT` "gobble up" the other tokens?

Comment: sorry, `defComm: TYPE arg EQUAL genericComment;` works. I realized just now :) The only doubt I have left is ... why `.*?` does not solve @, # etc and an input like `| Q1,0 = this is a text` after parse is like `| Q1,0 = thisisatext`

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to interpret your question (sorry).  I do think we need to be clear that `.` in a Lexer rule, is "any character", while `.` in a parser rule is "any token".  That is a really significant difference.

Comment: Honestly, `.*?` in any rule, only makes sense when in the context of what follows it, because if basically says "consumer 0 or more (unlimited) (characters|tokens), but only do so as long as they are not the next component in the rule evaluation. (for `genericComment`, it's the last part of `comment`, which is the last part of `line` where it is followed by `EOL` , so the `.*?` in `genericComment` consumes (non-greedily) any number of any token until it finds an `EOL` token.

Comment: Really thanks Mike... now it's clear to me ... initially with input like `|C10 = this is a comment` the result of genericComment was `thisisacomment` (I mean doing `genericComment().getText()` in `enterDefComm` Listener) but with a TOKEN like `ANY_SPACE: SINGLE_SPACE+;`  and  `SINGLE_SPACE: ' ';` it works: `genericComment().getText()` -> `this is a comment` .... Thanks for your advice, Mike!

Comment: Actually, you can get THAT benefit by sending whitespace to the `HIDDEN` channel instead of `skip`ping it.  By sending to `channel(HIDDEN)` you don't have to account for whitespace in your parser rules, but it's still included if you call `getText()` for a rule.